# How to install wayland on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS?

Tags: 16.04, wayland

Is there any official repository to install wayland on Ubuntu 16.04?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### **** Warning : The below commands may break your system. Use it with caution****

You can use Wayland Daily build [ppa](https://launchpad.net/~wayland.admin/+archive/ubuntu/daily-builds) (extremely unstable)for installing latest Wayland on your system. since it's only for testing/experimentation there is a high probability that you will break your system

**Steps to install**

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:wayland.admin/daily-builds
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install weston xwayland
```

open terminal and run

```
weston
```

This will launch weston inside X

if you want the full experience, open virtual terminal (alt+ctrl+f1) and use command

```
weston-launch
```

Note : Wayland works better with opensouce video drivers. Wayland may or may not work on proprietary video drivers.

To remove experimental wayland/weston from your system use

```
ppa-purge ppa:wayland.admin/daily-builds
```

Comment: Quoting: *IMPORTANT: This is for experimentation/testing only, not for production use. Before upgrading your system to a new Ubuntu release you should probably run 'ppa-purge ppa:wayland.admin/daily-builds' first.* You have been warned.

Comment: @CelticWarrior updated my answer

Comment: Only a terminal without UTF8 support?